# Fairly new to R , can anyone tell me the difference between the queries?

Tags: r

```
penguins %>% group_by(island, species) %>% drop_na() %>% 
  summarise(meaxbill =  max(penguins$bill_length_mm))


penguins %>% group_by(island, species) %>% drop_na() %>% 
  summarise(meaxbill =  max(bill_length_mm))
```

Comment: The second query uses masked data-variables.  Normally, in a regular R environment, you can only access the `bill_length_mm` column, from the `penguins` table, by tying `penguins$bill_length_mm`.  However, within the context of these `dplyr` operations, the column is ["masked"](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#data-masking) as a ["data-variable"](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#data--and-env-variables), and you can refer to it simply as `bill_length_mm`: R will know to look for a `bill_length_mm` column in `penguins`.

Comment: If you use the pipe operator `%>%` like with `dplyr` package you don't need to assign the full dataframe and column name. This is because you start with the dataframe name `penguins` and each column coming after the pipe operator is referred to this dataframe, so you do not need to write each time penguins$ in context with the pipe operator.

Comment: I'll word it a little more strongly: when using the pipe operator `%>%` and the `dplyr` package, you ***should not*** use the dataframe name with the column names (`$`-indexing); while it works sometimes, if anything in the pipeline removes, adds, or reorders the rows, then your subsequent calculations will be wrong. It isn't that you don't *need* to assign the dataframe name, it's that if you do use it then you are likely corrupting your data. The first code is broken, do not trust it. (Whether it is truly corrupted or not may be contextual; I don't know if it corrupts it here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll word it a little more strongly: when using the pipe operator `%>%` and the `dplyr` package, you ***should not*** use the dataframe name with the column names (`$`-indexing); while it works sometimes, if anything in the pipeline removes, adds, or reorders the rows, then your subsequent calculations will be wrong. It isn't that you don't *need* to assign the dataframe name, it's that if you do use it then you are likely corrupting your data. The first code is broken, do not trust it. (Whether it is truly corrupted or not may be contextual; I don't know if it corrupts it here.)

Let me demonstrate. If we want to know the max bill length (mm) of all of the penguins, by `sex`, we should do something like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
data("penguins", package = "palmerpenguins")

penguins %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  summarize(maxbill = max(bill_length_mm))
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   sex    maxbill
#   <fct>    <dbl>
# 1 female    58  
# 2 male      59.6
```

If for some reason we instead use `penguins$bill_length_mm`, then we'll see this:

```r
penguins %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  summarize(maxbill = max(penguins$bill_length_mm))
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   sex    maxbill
#   <fct>    <dbl>
# 1 female      NA
# 2 male        NA
```

which will likely encourage us to add `na.rm=TRUE` to the data, and we'll get a seemingly valid-ish number:

```r
penguins %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  summarize(maxbill = max(penguins$bill_length_mm, na.rm = TRUE))
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   sex    maxbill
#   <fct>    <dbl>
# 1 female    59.6
# 2 male      59.6
```

but the problem is that `max(.)` is being passed *all* of `penguins$bill_length_mm`, not just the values within each group.

In this case, the use of `penguins$` is not a syntax error, it is a logical error, and there is no way for `dplyr` or anything else in R to know that what you are doing is not what you really need. It works, because `max(.)` sees a vector and it returns a single number; then `summarize(.)` sees a single number and assigns it to a new variable.

And in this case, our results are corrupted.

---

The only time it may be *valid* to use `penguins$` in this is if we truly need to bring in a number or object from outside of the current "view" of the data. Realize that the data that `summarize(.)` sees is not the data that started in the pipe: it has been filtered (by `drop_na()`), it might be changed (if we `mutate`d some columns into it) or reordered (if we `arrange` the data).

But if we need to find out the percentage of the max bill length with respect to the max of the original data, we might do this:

```r
penguins %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  summarize(
    maxbill = max(bill_length_mm),
    maxbill_ratio = max(bill_length_mm) / max(penguins$bill_length_mm, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   sex    maxbill maxbill_ratio
#   <fct>    <dbl>         <dbl>
# 1 female    58           0.973
# 2 male      59.6         1
```

(Recall that we needed to add `na.rm=TRUE` in that call because one of the rows has an `NA` ... and the data we see in that last `max` has not been filtered/cleaned by the `drop_na()` call.)